# insert whole list of data into sql database table in xamarin.android

Tags: list, stored-procedures, datatable, xamarin.android, asmx

i'm trying to create an application where data in a list must be inserted into a database table at once. I made some research and found out that this is possible using user-defined table types where in c# a datatable is used and passed to a stored procedure that is executed. now my problem is that there are no data tables in Xamarin.Android. so I thought to use a list instead. my idea was to create a list in the application and pass it to the webservice method, and in my webservice method I receive the list and convert it to a datatable then pass it as a parameter to the stored procedure. I wrote the following codes:

in my webservice:

```
[WebMethod]
        public bool insrt_dt(List<Class1> lst)
        {
            SqlParameter param;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(new DBConnection().ConnectionString);
            DataTable dt = list_to_dt(lst);
            
            
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Customers", conn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                param = new SqlParameter("@tblcustomers", dt);
                param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                param.DbType = DbType.String;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                int a=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (a > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;



        }
    }
```

Class1:

```
 public class Class1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }

    }
```

in my Xamarin.Android app

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            btn.Click += delegate
            {
                wr.WebService1 ws = new wr.WebService1();
                wr.Class1 class1 = new wr.Class1();
                List<wr.Class1> lst = new List<wr.Class1>(){
                new wr.Class1() { id = 1, name = "hgf", country = "khg" },
                 new wr.Class1() { id = 2, name = "hgf", country = "khg"} };
               
                ws.insrt_dt(lst);
                ws.insrt_dtCompleted += Ws_insrt_dtCompleted;
            };




        }

        private void Ws_insrt_dtCompleted(object sender, wr.insrt_dtCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool l = e.Result;
            if (l == true)
                Toast.MakeText(this, "khh", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            else
                Toast.MakeText(this, "ijo'pioo", ToastLength.Long).Show();

}
        }
```

but I keep getting this error:
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<app_dt.wr.Class1>' to 'app_dt.wr.Class1[]
so I used these lines instead

```
                new wr.Class1() { id = 1, name = "hgf", country = "khg" },
                 new wr.Class1() { id = 2, name = "hgf", country = "khg"} };
                wr.Class1[] class1s = lst.ToArray();
                ws.insrt_dt(class1s);
```

now I don't get an error, but it doesn't work, I mean why does it say that the webservice method input must be an array and I've created it as a list. any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, Xamarin do not support `System.Data.SqlClient`. If you want to use the database for the Xamarin android project, you could use the `SQLite.NET`.

Install the package from the NuGet.

NuGet: `sqlite-net-pcl` https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

For the code sample about how to use the database in Xamarin, you could check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

For Xamarin.Android, you could check the sample code in the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: Any update for this case? Have you solved this issue?